# .NET SQL CE Core - Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: .net, sql

I am using SQL CE to store data in my application. I got an error with the below code after executing it for around 3000 times:

> "Not enough storage is available to complete this operation"

The error is happened on a LIVE application.

```
SqlCeConnection connection;
SqlCeTransaction transaction;

try
{
    connection = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    SqlCeCommand deleteCmd = connection.CreateCommand(); 
    deleteCmd.CommandText ="Delete from EJData where ID=@id"; 
    deleteCmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, Int32.MaxValue.ToString().Length, "ID"); 
    adapter.DeleteCommand = deleteCmd;
    adapter.DeleteCommand.Transaction = transaction;
    DataRow[] r = dataSet.Tables[0].Select("ID >=" + firstRecordID + " and ID<=" + lastRecordID); 
    foreach (DataRow row in r) 
    {
        row.Delete();
    }

    adapter.Update(dataSet,"EJData" ); 
    transaction.Commit(CommitMode.Immediate); 
    transaction.Dispose();
    transaction = null; 
} 

catch ( ... )

{
    ...
}

finally

{ 
    if (adapter.DeleteCommand != null) 
    {
        adapter.DeleteCommand.Dispose();
    }

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: The 3000 times - is that 3000 calls to this method? Or one call with 3000 items in the loop? I wonder if the transaction is simply too big, and a number of smaller transactions might be more successful.

Comment: even due not recommended, try adding GC.Collect(); after connection.Close();

Answer (score 0):

when declaring the parameter use this:
deleteCmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int, "ID");